# Debugging a slow Wordpress SQL query (because of ORDER BY?)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, query-optimization

The section fronts on a Wordpress site I help out with have just started loading slow, and I traced it to the SQL query that loads the posts for the page, and timed a few different queries to see what's causing the slow-down.

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,12,13,14) )
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 12
```

Takes 8.3 seconds to run.

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,12,13,14) )
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 12
```

Takes 6.5 seconds.

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,12,13,14) )
LIMIT 12
```

Takes 31ms.

The SQL call is coming from Wordpress core so I don't really have control over that, but is there anything that I can do with the database or tell the company that maintains the database to do/check?

Comment: Make an explain for each of this queries, to see their execution plans.

Comment: I take a look to a Wordpres database, apparently there is a index on 'post_date` EXPLAIN will help for execution plan comprehension

Comment: The standard WordPress database definition is [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description). If you know what plugin generates this query, please [edit] your question to tell us.

Comment: @O.Jones The query is generated by the get_posts function of the WP_Query class in core wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth using EXPLAIN to see how MySQL is using indexes (or not), and how it's optimizing the sorting (or not). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

There might be an index that can help improve performance transparently, i.e. without requiring any change to the query in the Wordpress source code. That's not always possible, though.

There are other debugging techniques. I show some in a presentation: [Sql query patterns, optimized](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-query-patterns-optimized)

---

When asking questions about query optimization on Stack Overflow, you need to provide three things before you can get an answer:

- The query (which you have done).
- The SHOW CREATE TABLE result for each of the tables in the query, so we can see the data types, and current indexes and constraints.
- The output of EXPLAIN for the query (or queries) given your current table.

Sometimes it's helpful to use db-fiddle.com to create a minimal example that reproduces the test case, for folks to test with. I know you can't fill that with enough data to make it take 8 seconds, but at least enough to produce the same EXPLAIN result.

Comment: It's all stock Wordpress code.  Even the generated SQL query that I'm starting with (I'm just making edits to it in Sequel Pro to try to figure out the bottle neck).  Info about the posts table can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_posts) and the term_relationships [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_term_relationships).  I've never used an EXPLAIN before today, and when I do it in Sequel Pro, it returns a table with 10 columns.  I'm not sure the best way to provide that.

Comment: Normally I copy the EXPLAIN output as a text block and paste it into the Stack Overflow markdown editor, indented 4 spaces so it is formatted like a code block.

Comment: I'm looking at the indexes of those tables, and I see it's already got an index to help it. But I would guess it has reordered the tables so `wp_term_relationships` is read first, then joined to `wp_posts` by the primary key of the latter table. I can think of a few different ways to rewrite the query that would improve it (one of which is the one posted in Rick James' answer), but I assume any solution that involves changing WP code isn't ideal.

Comment: In that case, all I can suggest is delete as much of your older data as you can, so the size of the dataset it needs to sort is smaller. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

- See Bill's answer
- You seem to have a zillion posts.  It takes time to check each for the desired taxonomy.
- Then the query lists them whether or not they match.  That is, `LEFT` is probably not what you wanted.
- `GROUP BY` is possibly unneeded.  (Or the `LEFT JOIN` can be turned into an `EXISTS`.)
- `INDEX(term_taxonomy_id, wp_term_relationships)` on
  table `wp_term_relationships` may help.

This may be a better way to phrase the query (in addition to the added index):

```
SELECT  p.ID
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT tr.object_id
             FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
             WHERE tr.term_taxonomy_id IN (4,12,13,14)
         ) AS ids
    JOIN wp_posts AS p  ON p.id = ids.object_id
    ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 12
```

If you are not actually displaying just the IDs, it would be better to proceed with a `JOIN` to get more info for actually displaying.  But I guess WP thwarts that optimization.

Comment: I assume it's not a preferred option to rewrite the WP query, since it's part of stock WP code.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Yeah, well, there is only so much that can be done when constrained by a framework.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an [index](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Indexes_6) appropriate to this particular query. It looks to me like you could use an extra one to help optimize that `ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT 12` stuff.

Try adding an index on `wp_posts` containing these columns: `(ID, post_date DESC)`.

To do that you can use wp-cli:

```bash
wp db query "ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD KEY goodspeed_id_date (ID, post_date DESC);"
```

Or, if you do it via phpmyadmin use these two SQL statements.

```sql
SET @@sql_mode := REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'NO_ZERO_DATE', '');
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD KEY goodspeed_id_date (ID, post_date DESC);
```

Please, please, please, let us know whether you are successful with this.

Comment: I'm pretty new to indexes, yesterday I added an index for post_date (and only post_date), and that didn't seem to make a difference.  I haven't tried making one with ID and post_date.  And I'm not 100% sure how to make it DESC with Sequel Pro, which is what I'm using and it has a built-in interface for adding indexes.  I guess I could just run the queries you gave for phpmyadmin?

Comment: The DESC doesn't matter very much. It's ok if you leave it out.